# Unreliable discovery for elasticsearch nodes on ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch (0.90.x) with the cloud-aws plugin. Sometimes nodes running on different machines aren't able to discover each other ("waited for 30s and no initial state was set by the discovery"). I've set "discovery.ec2.ping_timeout" to "15s", but this doesn't seem to help. Are there other settings that might make a difference?

```
discovery:
    type: ec2
    ec2:
        ping_timeout: 15s
```

Comment: Should add that I last saw this problem with elasticsearch 0.90.2; too early to tell if I'll see it again with 0.90.3.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are aware of this blog post: [http://www.elasticsearch.org/tutorials/elasticsearch-on-ec2/](https://web.archive.org/web/20150109115804/http://www.elasticsearch.org/tutorials/elasticsearch-on-ec2). It explains the plugin settings in depth.

Adding cluster name, like so

```
cluster.name: your_cluster_name 
discovery:
    type: ec2
...
```

might help.

Comment: Thanks; I do have a cluster name set, and am familiar with the tutorial. The tutorial is quite old and not authoritative ("I couldn't find much documentation regarding this setting, but it appears to be..."). I've come across a bunch of settings in the mailing list archives (discovery.zen.fd.ping_retries, discovery.zen.ping.timeout, discovery.zen.fd.ping_timeout), but it's hard to know which of these would help, or even do something!